# MySql Query- Order By clause with field() method

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have the following MySql Query:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY FIELD(
priority,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,....,300,0),date_fixed ASC, sno DESC";
```

In fact, i need to display record `ordered by priority ASC` but also want to keep all the record having the `priority = 0` at the end of the any other numerical value. The above query working fine but I think its not worth to write values starting from `1 to 300` and at the end i just put `0`.

My Question is that any shortcut way to achieve the `ResultSet` as `Orderby priority ASC` and keeping the `0th` priorities at the end?

Comment: `ORDER BY priority=0, priority`

Comment: @Akina great job... This is what i will call you genius

Comment: Really, I just worry we're setting the Genius bar  too low these days.